# Conditional parameters of a function in an interface

Tags: typescript

I have a component for uploading files and in this component the user can upload a single file or multiple files based on the `multiple` property that the user passes to the component. The user can also provide an `onChange` function where it will receive the files that have been uploaded. If the user uploads a file, I will pass onChange a `File` and if the user uploads multiple files, I will pass onChange a `File[]`. Is there a way to declare an interface that, based on boolean prop, can decide what version of a function it should be?

```
export interface FilePickerProps {
  multiple?: boolean
  // something like this
  onChange: multiple ? (selectedFiles: File[]) => void : (selectedFiles: File) => void
}
```

I would like that when passing the `onChange` prop I can receive the correct types for the selectedFiles parameter, if it is a `File` or a `File[]`.

Comment: You can't do it with an interface, but you can make a discriminated union type that works this way, as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvopAw). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes thanks! In addition to using the solution you provide, I needed to cast my function before calling so TypeScript wouldn't complain about it, so something like this: (onChange as MultipleFileOnChange)(selectedFiles) and (onChange as SingleFileOnChange)(selectedFiles[0])

Comment: Without a [mre] I'm not sure why that would happen, but I guess it's out of scope. I'll write up my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of conditional dependence of `onChange` on `multiple` isn't really well represented by a single [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces).  Instead, it would be more appropriate to use a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), where `multiple` is the *discriminant* property.  For example:

```
type FilePickerProps = {
  multiple: true
  onChange: (selectedFiles: File[]) => void
} | {
  multiple?: false
  onChange: (selectedFiles: File) => void
}
```

Now if `multiple` is `true`, then `onChange` accepts an array of `File`s. But if `multiple` is `false` or missing or `undefined`, then `onChange` accepts only a single `File`.

Let's test it:

```
function foo(f: FilePickerProps, files: File[]) {
  if (f.multiple) {
    f.onChange(files); // okay
  } else {
    files.forEach(file => f.onChange(file)); // okay
  }
}
```

Looks good. The compiler can follow the logic whereby a check of `f.multiple` affects the apparent type of `f.onChange`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgGwgBTgYwNYQE7OwezAGcoBeKAbwCgooBbAVwWDjCQC4phsGIap8AOwDCACwCGggOYROACiIQkaYBAAm8JEU6aIAbQC6ASjIA+KADd8cNVQC+UAD6V+jZqyQB+TgDNxCRX4hMUkZeUVlVQ1ECG1YGJNScysbeyoqHwZBFTghKB98fDkfHRjUTBw8QiIAGnyYuN1DE2paOB8oYoA6NxY2CBb+Wh8u4IlpCGKGowBuKAB6eYEMcRB+ByVFF1phhq6C7ABRcTRRKaQzfNGRcZlzgdmFpfwVtdo7NKogA)